# Как отловить проблему связанную с mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, администрирование

В общем есть сайт на поддержке, и сайт каждый день +- в одно и тоже время сайт зависает и не отвечает на запросы в течении 6-10 минут. (график с сервиса host-tracker http://joxi.ru/brRZGx6U7bbQar). Причем через какое-то время эти зависания смещаются на какое-то количество часов и начинают каждый день повторяться в другое время.

Мы начали копать проблему и поняли что все сводится к Mysql. В это время когда начинает зависать сайт, load average вырастает до 45-50. И mysql начинает очень долго обрабатывать любые запросы которые на него приходят, если перезапустить mysql, то зависания сразу же прекращаются и нагрузка падает.

Проверили cron скрипты(отключали полностью в то время как происходит зависания) не помогает. Анализировали slow-query запросы которые пишет mysql, все они не создают нагрузки (менее 0.1сек) если их запускать в то время когда сервер работает. Смотрели оперативку, с ней все тоже в порядке, в swap не уходит.

В общем суть вопроса в том, как дальше анализировать проблему? Хотя бы понять в чем конкретно проблема.

Comment: А на MySQL запущен Event Scheduler? там нет ничего предосудительного?

Comment: Он выключен http://joxi.ru/eAOdGO1C9ggE6r

Comment: Смотрите железо  и смотрите окружение - что именно происходит в это время - возможно, канал связи, возможно, что еще - смотрите трассировку запросов. У вас есть хорошая привязка - почти одно и то же время.

Comment: я бы для начала постарался посмотреть `show processlist` в MySQL во время этих зависаний. посмотреть количество коннектов и что конкретно они в этот момент выполняют. если там обычные запросы от сайта, то либо чем то сильно нагружен диск (не обязательно MySQL), либо запросов на сайт в этот момент слишком много (и/или они тяжелые), например от ботов. Тогда анализировать логи http

Comment: Тут можно хоть что предположить, надо анализировать всё. Не думаю что проблема в `mysql` - смотрели `show processlist`? Сколько на момент нагрузки там было запросов? в `htop` заглядывали? в `cron`? Запросто может запускаться скрипт который работает с БД, но он не успевает закончится раньше, чем запускается новая задача, в итоге снежный ком и периодичность проблемы.